# calling a function in matlab and letting the caller determine the number of output arguments at runtime

Tags: matlab, function

Is there a way to generalize the following? (**note: `nargout_requested` may not be known except at runtime**)

```
function outputs = apply_and_gather(f, args, nargout_requested)
  switch nargout_requested
    case 0
      f(args{:});
      outputs = {};
    case 1
      o1 = f(args{:});
      outputs = {o1};
    case 2
      [o1,o2] = f(args{:});
      outputs = {o1,o2};
    case 3
      [o1,o2,o3] = f(args{:});
      outputs = {o1,o2,o3};
      ...
```

In other words, I want to call a function with a cell array of arguments, and assign the function's outputs to a cell array, and request a certain # of output arguments.

In python this would just be:

```
outputs = f(*args)
```

but Matlab requires you to tell a function how many arguments you want before you call it, and gives you an error if you have too many output arguments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aha, I think I have it. I still have to special-case the number of outputs between zero and nonzero:

```
function outputs = apply_and_gather(f, args, nargout_requested)
switch nargout_requested
    case 0
        f(args{:});
        outputs = {};
    otherwise
        outputs = cell(1, nargout_requested);
        [outputs{:}] = f(args{:});
end
```

example usage:

```
>> outputs=apply_and_gather(@polyfit,{[0:0.1:1 1.1],[0:0.1:1 1],3},3)

outputs = 

    [1x4 double]    [1x1 struct]    [2x1 double]
```

If I don't special-case for zero output arguments, I get this:

```
>> outputs=apply_and_gather2(@polyfit,{[0:0.1:1 1.1],[0:0.1:1 1],3},0)
The left hand side is initialized and has an empty range of indices.
However, the right hand side returned one or more results.

Error in apply_and_gather2 (line 3)
    [outputs{:}] = f(args{:});
```

Comment: I think you can also avoid passing `nargout_requsted` and use the built in  [`nargout`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/nargout.html) instead

Comment: Maybe I didn't make that clear in my question: I have reasons for manually specifying the number of arguments I wanted. This was for a test harness.

Comment: What the `apply_and_gather` function does is to subvert the normal multiple-arguments method of MATLAB and instead return the results as a cell array. The `nargout` value for `apply_and_gather` would always be 1.

Answer (score 0):

To call another function, requesting a variable number of outputs, use some non-obvious syntax magic, like this:

```
function outputs=  = apply_and_gather(f, args, nargout_requested)
    outputs= cell(1, requested);  %Preallocate to define size
    [outputs{:}] = f(args{:});
```

---

To return a variable number of arguments, look into `varargout`.  Your code would look like this:

```
function varargout =  = apply_and_gather(f, args, nargout_requested)
    varargout = cell(1, requested);

    % ... your code here, setting values to the varargout cell
```

Comment: No, I don't want to return multiple outputs; I want to return a single output that is a cell array, whose elements are the k outputs of the function I call, where k is known only at runtime.

Comment: yeah, I figured that out too (the use of `[somevar{:}]` ). You have to special-case 0 arguments, though. (see my answer)